# Could someone explain where is mistake in binary addition method?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

The method that adds one binary to another one, I had assignment and an overview says that this method does not work. I run test cases with different binary numbers it outputs correct results.
Here is the code:

```
public void add(BinaryNumber aBinaryNumber) {
        
        //Creating local variables for storing carry value and temporal sum array
        int carry = 0;
        int[] temp = new int[data.length];
        
        if(data.length != aBinaryNumber.getLength()) {
            //Checking if length of two binary numbers are coincide
            System.out.println("Lengths of binary numbers do not coincide.");
        }
        else {
            //populating temporary array after sum 
            for(int i=0; i< data.length; i++) {
                
                if((data[i] + aBinaryNumber.getDigit(i) + carry) == 0 ) {
                    
                    temp[i] = 0;
                    carry=0;
                }
                else if((data[i] + aBinaryNumber.getDigit(i) + carry) == 1 ) {
                    
                    temp[i] = 1;
                    carry=0;
                }
                else if((data[i] + aBinaryNumber.getDigit(i) + carry) == 2 ) {
                    
                    if(i==(data.length - 1)) {
                        //Setting overflow flag to true, if there is a carryover digit at the addition
                        overflow = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    temp[i] = 0;
                    carry=1;
                }
                else if((data[i] + aBinaryNumber.getDigit(i) + carry) == 3 ) {
                    
                    if(i==(data.length - 1)) {
                        overflow = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    temp[i] = 1;
                    carry=1;
                }
            }
            
            if(carry == 1) {
                
                System.out.println("Sum resulted overflow.");
            }
        }
        
        data = temp;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //All calculations made using little-endian format.
        BinaryNumber data1 = new BinaryNumber("1011");// decimal 13
        BinaryNumber data2 = new BinaryNumber("0100");// decimal 2
        BinaryNumber data5 = new BinaryNumber("1110");// decimal 7
        BinaryNumber data6 = new BinaryNumber("1011");// decimal 13
        
        
        //Performing addition operation with two binary numbers. 
        data1.add(data2);// result 1111, decimal 15
        
        data5.add(data6);// sum resulted overflow
        
        //Clearing overflow flag
        data5.clearOverflow();
        
        //Performing addition of two binary numbers that have different length
        data1.add(data3); //addition of two binary numbers that have different length

    }
```

I run test cases with different inputs (examples above), but my teacher says that method does not work.Could someone point where is mistake

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your binary numbers are reversed.  Seven is normally "0111" and not "1110" as you have it.  Could the input format be the problem?

Comment: Assignment sad I need to use little endian format instead of big endianwhen calculating